# how to properly close a tkinter window with background threads updaing the gui

Tags: python, multithreading, user-interface, tkinter, exit

I have a Tkinter app which built of single window and several frames, each frame is a class. Some frames has threads that changes the GUI components (e.g entry) on the context of receiving a message from socket.

```
root = tk.Tk()
gui = MainFrame(root)   # this class holds the frames
root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", functools.partial(gui.close, root))
...
root.mainloop()
```

The problem: when the user press the "X" button the following `close` func is called:

```
def close(self):
    self.frame1.close() # turns the while condition of the thread to be false and call join()
    self.frame2.close() # "
    ...
    root.destroy()
```

The internal threads are running in while loop (with condition) trying to update an GUI components and after call to `close()` they get stuck on a single line of code without rising an exception.
e.g `self.entry.configure(state='disabled')`. Then the `join()` call never ends.

This way the code is stuck and the GUI is not closing. I can call `root.destroy()` at the beginning of the function then the GUI will be closed but the code is still running (stuck)

**How should i prevent this stuck or force killing my threads?**

Thank you

Comment: You can force kill the thread when the application exits by setting `daemon=True` when creating the thread object. However, as you say in the question *"The internal threads are running in while loop (with condition)"*, you can terminate the while loop by changing the *condition* before destroying tkinter window.

Comment: I don't know how it can be stacked on `self.entry.configure(state='disabled')` - it may only raise error. And if you run it in thead then it could raise error because `tkinter` (like many other GUIs) doesn't like to run in threads. Threads should change globla values or use `Queue` to send values to main thread and main thread should change values in widgets. OR maybe you have code in some `try/except` and it can't display error message. It could stuck if you would use some `threading.Lock()` or something similar.

Comment: @acw1668 i tried to set `daemon=True` to all my threads and it didn't work :( regarding your second suggestion it is already implemented that way. when the "X" is pressed the while iteration never finished because some internal line is on blocking.
@furas there is no `try/catch`, i checked it well and it gets stuck every time on different line but every time it's a GUI component related similar to the one i mentioned. my frames are classes and the GUI components (e.g entry, label..) are members of this class. is this might be wrong practice?